# How to change the version of fileoutputcommitter algorithm in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

By default spark (2.4.4) use MapReduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 1. I am trying it to change it to version 2. spark-UI and `sparkCtx._conf.getAll()` shows version 2 but pyspark still writes the data in S3 using version 1(temporary folders are creating).    I have tried these things.

1. setting `spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version   2` in spark-defaults.conf
2. defining config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version","2") for spark session.
3. setting option in df.write like this: 
   `df.write.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")`

[image: spark config]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but pyspark still writes the data in S3 using version 1(temporary folders are creating).

First of all both v1 and v2 algorithms uses temporary files. As explained in the [MAPREDUCE-6336](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6336)

> Algorithm version 2 changes the behavior of commitTask, recoverTask, and commitJob.
>
> 1. commitTask renames all files in
>      $joboutput/_temporary/$appAttemptID/_temporary/$taskAttemptID/
>      to $joboutput/
> 2. recoverTask is a nop strictly speaking, but for
>      upgrade from version 1 to version 2 case, it checks if there
>      are any files in
>      $joboutput/_temporary/($appAttemptID - 1)/$taskID/
>      and renames them to $joboutput/
> 3. commitJob deletes $joboutput/_temporary and writes
>      $joboutput/_SUCCESS

So please make sure that you're actually seeing the changes corresponding to v1 not v2.

Additionally `spark.hadoop` options are applicable to context not specific write, so your 3rd attempt shouldn't work at all.

The remaining ones should be equivalent (the second one, if set before `SparkContext` is started).