# Spark save csv file without _temporary folder in object storage

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to write csv files to a remote file system using pyspark and set partition to 2048 to make those csv files small enough. This remote file system is an object storage service, but it provides a class that allows it to be used like hadoop. The code I use to write CSV files to this remote file system is very simple, similar to the following:

```py
df = ... # obtain data from database
df.write.csv(dsn, mode="overwrite", sep=sep, encoding=encoding, quote="\"",
                             escape="\"")
```

The problem I encountered is that when PySpark writes data to the `_temporary` folder, it is very fast and can be completed within 6 minutes. However, it takes an hour and a half to move the content out of the `_temporary` folder.

I am using Spark 2.4.0 (hard to update to a newer version), and I would like to know if there is a way to write the CSV files directly without using the _temporary folder.

After hours of searching, I have found many related topics, but none of them can solve my problem.

- `spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2`. But based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364226/how-to-change-the-version-of-fileoutputcommitter-algorithm-in-pyspark), v2 algorithm also used temporary file.
- [change output committer](https://lists.apache.org/thread/xmovx2h45drm5w2c83gpxn0xocj06j5g), but this seems to work for parquet only, and I need to write csv file.
- [zero rename committer](https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases), but this seems to work for address with "s3:\", may be with a higher spark version.

Answer (score 0):

the hadoop s3a "zero rename committer" works with CSV files and is compatible with spark 2.4; you just need a version including the spark-hadoop-cloud module *and* Hadoop 3.2+ binaries

it only works with AWS S3 and very compatible third party stores, through the s3a:// URLs.